# My Hostname is not getting updated in RHEL VM using CentOS

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, centos7, rhel, rhel7

I have created a RHEL VM with CentOS7.

I tried to change the Hostname in "/etc/hosts" file.

Eventhough I have updated the localhost name as expected(10.x.x.xx), my Terminal still shows as ["username@10 ~]$

Answer (score 1):

Try to update `/etc/hostname` aswell.

If that doesn't work, use `hostnamectl set-hostname NEWNAME`

Then restart the service with `systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed`